# How to disable a particular config component on specific action in YII2?

Tags: yii

i have a user component in my web config file which is working fine.

```
$config = [

    'components' => [

        'user' => [

            'class' => 'common\components\User'

        ],

        ...

    ],

];
```

except on a page where I want to use a different user file. Is it possible to disable the particular component in Yii for a particular action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways foe example  You could declare two different components

```
$config = [

'components' => [

    'user' => [

        'class' => 'common\components\User'

    ],

   'user1' => [

        'class' => 'common\components\MyAlternativeUser'

    ],

    ...

 ],

];
```